# can't see JSESSIONID in browser network JBoss JAAS authorisation

Tags: session, cookies, jboss, session-cookies

I use JBoss EAP 7.1.0 and JAAS authorization. My security realm :

```
 </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="powSecurityDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/powds"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM POW_USER_CURRENT_PASSWORD PASS JOIN POW_USER US ON PASS.USER_ID=US.ID WHERE US.USER_NAME_SEARCH = ? and US.ACTIVE='Y' and US.LOCKED !='Y'"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT UGA.GROUP_NAME, 'Roles' FROM POW_USER_GRP_ASSOC UGA JOIN POW_USER US ON US.ID = UGA.USER_ID WHERE USER_NAME_SEARCH= ?"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:///${jboss.server.config.dir}/rolesMapping-roles.properties"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

And after user successful login I can't see JSESSIONID cookies in browser network :
[image]
[image]
But I can see them in browser settings:
[image]
Why I have this problem? Maybe I need some additional configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that JSSESIONID cookies path wasn't "/". So I add in my ear file next config:

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <shared-session-config xmlns="urn:jboss:shared-session-config:1.0">
        <session-config>
            <cookie-config>
                <path>/</path>
            </cookie-config>
        </session-config>
    </shared-session-config>
</jboss>
```